# Как открывать и закрывать ссылку по таймеру?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Подскажите как сделать так чтоб ссылка появлялась в определенное время и потом скрывалась тоесть будет проводится мероприятие в одно и то же время онлайн, есть график мероприятий в каждый день в одно и тоже время скажем в 21:00 как сделать чтоб ссылка открывалась в 20:45 и пряталась в 22:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать проверку текущего времени, если текущее время попадает в интервал времени то ссылка открыта.

```
$start = "01:00:00";
$end = "02:00:00";
$cur_time = date('h:i:s');
if ($cur_time > $start && $cur_time < $end) {
    echo "Доступно";
}
```

Для установки часового пояса используйте `date_default_timezone_set();`